# Are there any satellites in UHF that do not use AX.25? Which of them are in working state? Is the communication to them open?

Tags: digital-modes, satellites

I have a custom digital transceiver and will like to communicate with digital satellites in the UHF band. It might be fun to try different protocols other than commonly used (like AX.25) as well!

Comment: What's a "custom protocol"?

Comment: By Custom protocol, I mean non-standard protocols.
Protocols apart from standards as AX.25

Comment: Still not sure what you mean. Every satellite is using *some kind* of standard. Otherwise, it couldn't communicate with anything, and I doubt anyone has spent the money to launch a satellite and then not intend to communicate with it.

Comment: Okay, so may be some satellite with not so popular standard? Like I know for sure everyone doesn't use AX.25. So satellites that use communication protocols other that AX.25

Comment: If you know for sure, then why are you asking this question? You seem to already know the answer is yes.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [this list](http://www.dk3wn.info/p/?page_id=29535) of active amateur satellites, their up and downlink frequencies, and their modulations will help you. As for their protocols, you may have to google each one and find more details.